# Automatic scroll to element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

I have a div containing a chapter-list next to a video player. The current playing chapter has the class ".current" added.

```
<div class="hp_chapter--list">
    <ul class="hp_chapters">
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="0">00:00</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="1">00:02</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="2">00:03</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="3">00:04</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="4">00:05</a></li>
        <li class="current"><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="5">00:07</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There are long videos with a lot of chapters and I have a max height on the ".hp_chapter--list" with an overflow-y: auto. My question is, how can I make the div auto-scrolling so that the current list item is always visible?

Answer (score 0):

there are different ways to solve this, I can see that you are using jQuery so you can simply get the current class element, get the first element in the node list and simply scroll the view to that element.
Please note that I am not validating the existence of that class or element, so simply you can add an if conditional.

Otherwise if you want to scroll the element to the view you can add a listener to every a element in order to activate the action on a click event, on jquery see more [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/), on javascript vanilla see more here [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
$(".current").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

```html
<div class="hp_chapter--list">
    <ul class="hp_chapters">
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="0">00:00</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="1">00:02</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="2">00:03</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="3">00:04</a></li>
        <li class=""><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="4">00:05</a></li>
        <li class="current"><div><a class="hp_chapter" href="#" data-chapter="5">00:07</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried around with it, but unfortunately I didn't come to a working solution. Just to make sure, I don't want to scroll the whole window, I just want to scroll inside of the container, as the container is already visible all the time, but its content isn't because of the height limit.